# gspread keeps reverting to version 3.4.2 in Google Colab. I want to run 5.2.0 to avoid a time-out

Tags: google-colaboratory, gspread

I am using Google Colab.  gspread 3.4.2 seems to be the default.   I have uninstalled 3.4.2 and installed 5.2.0, but the next time I open the program with a new runtime, it is back to  3.4.2.

I am loading a large dataframe to a googlesheet, and it times out under 3.4.2, but works fine under 5.2.0.

What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google collaboration [online examples](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb) you can install libraries, `gspread` is already installed but using an old version so you can just upgrade it to latest version like so:

```
!pip install --upgrade gspread
```

This will install latest version of gspread.

Comment: I was doing an uninstall and install to fix the problem.  Your way is certainly easier.  I think that Colab keeps 3.4.2 as the default as I have to do the upgrade to 5.2.0 every time I use it.  Thank you.